# want to upload a pdf file into mysql using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, file, laravel-5

hello i am new in laravel. for my project purpose, i have a feature to upload a pdf file in database. but data not stored in databases.

here is my attempted codes=

controller-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $user = DB::table('users')->find($id);
        return view('posts', ['user' => $user]);
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        //dd(request()->all());
        $data = request()->validate(['pcaption' => 'required']);
         Auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
         dd(request()->all());

}
}
```

model-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

error from localhost-

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'post' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`pcaption`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (bh, 3, 2020-04-17 17:42:53, 2020-04-17 17:42:53))
```

that means the post data didn't save in database. where is my fault

Comment: You send this fields `pcaption, user_id, updated_at, created_at`, but by table settings `post` field can not be empty, because it have not default value

Comment: A pretty good write-up on that SQL error and how to resolve it here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/757/how-to-solve-mysql-exception-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1364-field-field-name-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Comment: i solved it to with a default value. but no improve, no path saved in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Database Table post column select as `Not Null`. For this reason you get this error. In your migration file you should use this to solve your problem

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ....
        $table->text('post')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No that means that your "posts" table has a column that called "post" and this column has no default value and does not accept to assume null.

So you can solve this problem like this:

```
create table posts ( 
     ..., 
     post varchar(10000) DEFAULT '' not null,
     ...
);
```

Comment: i solved it too with a default value. but still it not worked. no path saved in database